# How to get visibility into contributions to assets

Tags: financial-literacy, gnucash, double-entry, bookkeeping, financial-statements

I'm using double entry with Assets, Expenses, Income, Liabilities, and Equity.

To illustrate my question with easy round numbers: Income one month is 10k; 5k goes into an asset like a 401k account (or to reduce a Liability, like a mortgage principal), and Expenses are 8k.  (Doh!)

I'm looking for a report that shows me that I have a cash flow problem.

"Cash Flow", "Profit & Loss", "Balance Sheet", "Net Worth", etc. all don't show me that I have a problem (they say I'm spending 2k less than I'm making, and my net worth is going up by 2k/month, etc.).

Is there a standard report that should show me what I'm looking for?  Or is there a typical adjustment made to some report that will show what I'm looking for?

Tabular concrete (very exaggerated and simplified of course) example:

```
Starting Balances (years ago)     Withdraw  Deposit
  Asset: Checking                              100
  Liability: Loan                    50
  Equity                             50
Make Money        (today)
  Asset: Checking                              10
  Income: Sell Stuff                 10
Pay Loan          (today)
  Asset: Checking                    13
  Liability: Loan                              5
  Expenses: Interest Paid                      8
```

Do I just need to "close the books" frequently so that I can see this isn't sustainable?

Comment: "*and my net worth is going up by 2k/month*" If so, then you're doing it wrong.  That's because the $3K expenses you didn't pay from current income (`$5K + $8K - $10K = $3K`) must be accounted for on your balance sheet and net worth statement.  It's debt (either in the form of unpaid bills or unpaid CC charges).

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong, that's why I'm asking.... BUT: no, the money is actually coming from an existing asset account (e.g. a checking account that has surplus from last month).  In effect, I'm just *moving* 5k from a fluid asset to a 401(k) asset (for instance), so that has no effect on net worth.
I bring in 10k, spend 8k, and move 5k from one account to another.  Net increase is 2k.

Comment: I must be interpreting your question incorrectly. Please add a specific example in tabular form to your question.

Comment: added a table :)

Comment: @BobWalters Are you just trying to look at a graph of your checking account balance over time? Or are you looking for something more complex than that?

Comment: I was looking for something would say "this month, you spent more than you made" - even though the cause of that was essentially just a transfer from accumulated fluid assets to non-fluid assets, liabilities, etc.  Looks like Cash Flow is the one I want, and that I didn't have my accounts setup right for that to work.

And yeah: my actual case is way more complicated than that - enough so that I can't see it by just watching the total of my bank accounts.  Too many accounts and transactions for a vanilla spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cash flow report is where the problem should be manifested.  If you were a business, I would expect to see $2k of operating cash flow (revenue minus expenses) and -$5K of Investing/Financing cash flow (cash moved to increase an asset/reduce a liability), for a net change in cash of -$3k.

If your cash flow statement does not indicate this, then your cash flow report is wrong. Is your 401(k) possibly considered a cash account rather than an asset/investment?

Comment: Hmm: might be on to something.  I'm using gnucash.  Yes, looks like the cash flow report _is_ showing the mortgage liability reduction as it should, and in fact the retirement accounts were listed as Bank accounts.  So I changed those accounts to be Asset accounts.  But they're still not showing up when I regenerate the Cash Flow report.

This helps though.  It suggests that the Cash Flow report is the answer, and that I need to figure out how to get gnucash to treat those accounts right.  Cool - thanks!

Comment: @BobWalters this is why I use spreadsheets: double-entry accounting, while simple in concept, gets confusing in details.  One spreadsheet tracks my (current and future) cash, and the other tracks my assets and liabilities/debts.  The Cash Flow sheet is essentially a check register that looks forward into the future, and I always keep it up to date.  Net Worth is updated monthly.  Balance sheet and P&L are meaningless for a worker bee.